# can't start systemd in debian wheezy

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, uwsgi, systemd

I am using Debian Wheezy 7.8, and I want to start `uwsgi` as a service. I installed systemd (`apt-get install systemd`) and I edited grub (`vim /etc/default/grub`) and updated this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet init=/bin/systemd"`

I updated the grub and rebooted the system. However when I give this:

`systemctl`

I get this:

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.`

When I give `ps aux` I get this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  10648   808 ?        Ss   07:06   0:00 init [2]
```

Shouldn't PID 1 be systemd?

What am I doing wrong?